# Yii2 вывод данных из связанных страниц

Tags: php, yii2

Как вывести данные из трех связанных таблиц ?

Есть 3 таблицы:
Profile – со столбцом – id
Skill-dictionary – id, skill
Profile_skill – id, id_profile, id_skill
Profile_skill связана с двумя другими таблицами внешними ключами
fk_profile-skill_profile - id_profile ->id в таблице profile
fk_profile-skill_skill – id_skill id в Skill-dictionary

Необходимо во view profile вывести значение skill из Skill-dictionary (для соотв id profile)
Помогите, пожалуйста. Очень надо!
Если помимо запроса необходимо поменять $dataProvider, то тоже подскажите как.
Сейчас так:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
'query' => Profile::find(),
]);

return $this->render('index', [
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);
}
```

Comment: так а зачем вы привели этот фрагмент кода который не о чем не говорит ? покажите ваши модели к этим трем таблицам и как вы пытаетесь вывести эту информацию в виде

Answer (score 0):

Используйте relation `MANY_TO_MANY` в модели `Profile`, отредактируйте или добавьте метод `relations`:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'skills'  => [self::MANY_MANY, 'Skill', Profile_skill(id_skill, id_profile)'],
    );
}
```

Теперь для вывода вы можете использовать созданный нами `relation`:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $profile = Profile::with('skills')->find();
    return $this->render('index',[
        'dataProvider' => $profile,
    ])
}
```

Comment: Call to undefined method app\models\Profile::with()

Comment: @РоманПетров парень из мира ларавеля метод придумал, вот так верно: `$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query' => Profile::find()->with('skills')]);`

Comment: app\models\Profile has no relation named "skills