# В Yii2 вывести данные из трех таблиц

Tags: php, yii2

Есть 3 таблицы:

```
Profile (id)
Skill-dictionary (id, skill)
Profile_skill (id, id_profile, id_skill)
```

`Profile_skill` связана с двумя другими таблицами внешними ключами
`fk_profile-skill_profile` - `id_profile` -> `id` в таблице `profile`
`fk_profile-skill_skill` – `id_skill` -> `id` в `Skill-dictionary`

Необходимо, во view `profile` вывести значение `skill` из `Skill-dictionary` (для соотв. `id` в `profile`).

В моделе Profile.php:

```
public function getProfileSkills()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProfileSkill::className(), ['id_profile' => 'id'])
        ->joinWith(['id ProfileSkill'])
            ->joinWith(['id SkillDictionary']); 

    }
```

В контроллере Profile:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Profile::find(),
        ]);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы задавали этот вопрос [вчера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846365/yii2-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86) и вам дали на него ответ.

Потом вы задавали этот вопрос [тут](https://toster.ru/q/541064) и вам тоже дали на него ответ.

Может перестанете плодить темы и почитаете [офф документацию](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/db-active-record/) Yii2 ?

Comment: Ответы, которые мне дали, не работают. Т.е. по факту ответов нет

Comment: По факту вам лень потратить 2 минуты и почитать документацию. Перейдите по ссылке что я вам дал, и найдите там описание метода joinWith и сравните с тем как написали вы

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такой вариант:
1. в модели Profile_skill прописать две связи `hasOne()` с таблицами Skill и Profile. Например, для связи с Skill:

```
public function getNameSkill(){
    return $this->hasOne(Skill::className(), ['id' => 'id_skill']);
} //Аналогично и для Profile
```

2. используйте жадную загрузку при выполнении запроса Profile::find(), просто сделав следующее: Profile::find()->with(). И далее, когда во вьюшке надо будет вывести название скилла, делаете так:

```
//внутри виджета GridView:
'columns' => [
    ...
    [
        'attribute' => 'id_skill',
        'value' => function($data){
            return $data->nameSkill->skill;
        },
    ],
...
],
```

Надеюсь, Вам поможет этот ответ (: